# semantics on "std::hash<Key>()(k1)"

Tags: c++, function, templates, instantiation

As stated on [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), instances of this function of std::hash satisfy some properties. One of them, property 4 exactly is as follows:
For two parameters `k1` and `k2` that are equal, `std::hash<Key>()(k1) == std::hash<Key>()(k2)`

Where can I find semantics to explain `std::hash<Key>()(k1)`?

Comment: What exactly do you need explained?

Comment: The literal answer to your question is here: <https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Hash>. But you might want to look at other resources on the internet of what a hash function is

Comment: It means "*Create an unnamed object of type `std::hask<Key>` and call `operator()` on it, passing `k1` as argument.*". Might be easier to understand if you create a named object: `std::hash<Key> myHash; myHash(k1);`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. May I use "std::hash.operator()(k1)" or "std::hash(k1)" instead of "std::hash()(k1)"?

Comment: Try it, see if it works. (Spoiler - it doesn't.) `std::hash<T>().operator()(value)` would work, but there's no reason to spell it like this.

Comment: Nowadays, we'll often write `std::hash<Key>{}(k1)` instead of `std::hash<Key>()(k1)`. Maybe it's simpler to understand that way?

Comment: Great, "std::hash<Key>{}(k1)" looks much straightforward for me. I am very confused on difference between () and {} sometimes, under some situations.

Comment: `{}` is "make a thing", `()` can mean either "make a thing" or "call a thing".

Comment: Thanks all. Now I see my question is actually about DefaultConstructible at "https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultConstructible": two ways to define a temporary object. "std::hash<Key>() "or "std::hash<Key>{}" defines a temporary object of type "std::hash<Key>".

Answer (score 1):

In the expression `std::hash()(k1)`, the `std::hash()` part is constructing an object that has an `operator()` defined for the type of `k1`, then it is immediately calling the `operator()` on `k1`. One confusing thing is that `std::hash` is a template and in the expression written like that, without an explicit type, the template parameter is being deduced as the type of `k1`.

Basically to read that code you need to be aware that [`operator()` exists and can be overloaded with arbitrary argument types as a member function of a class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

`()`or `{}` after `std::hash` is needed here in order to instantiate a temporary object, as  [C++ named requirements: DefaultConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultConstructible).